# No Persister While Using NHibernate with Asp.Net Identity

Tags: c#

I am trying to implement the Microsoft Asp.Net Identity Security by following the project (https://github.com/milesibastos/NHibernate.AspNet.Identity). While trying to create a new user I am getting No persister Error in the Register ActionResult of the Account Controller.

```
    public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = model.UserName };

            var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                await SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            else
            {
                AddErrors(result);
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```